# Cannot resize partition on SD Card for beaglebone

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, filesystems, beaglebone

I've been through a few different tutorials and I've been unable to resize my BeagleBone Black's filesystem.

After running `/opt/scripts/tools/grow_partition.sh`, I get this output:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo /opt/scripts/tools/grow_partition.sh 
Media: [/dev/mmcblk1]

Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 116736 cylinders, 4 heads, 16 sectors/track
Old situation:
Units: 1MiB = 1024*1024 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start   End    MiB    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk1p1   *     1   3647   3647    3734528   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p2         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/mmcblk1p3         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/mmcblk1p4         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
New situation:
Units: 1MiB = 1024*1024 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start   End    MiB    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk1p1   *     1   3647   3647    3734528   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p2         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/mmcblk1p3         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/mmcblk1p4         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
Successfully wrote the new partition table

Re-reading the partition table ...
sfdisk: BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy
sfdisk: The command to re-read the partition table failed.
Run partprobe(8), kpartx(8) or reboot your system now,
before using mkfs
sfdisk: If you created or changed a DOS partition, /dev/foo7, say, then use dd(1)
to zero the first 512 bytes:  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/foo7 bs=512 count=1
(See fdisk(8).)
```

My `df -h` output:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  8.4M   91M   9% /run
/dev/mmcblk1p1  3.5G  3.2G   61M  99% /
tmpfs           247M  4.0K  247M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           247M     0  247M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            50M     0   50M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I've also attempted to do this manually by using the `fdisk` command, but that also has not worked. I can retry that method and give output of commands if you think it will help solve this problem.

Tutorials I've attempted:

- https://www.element14.com/community/thread/73919/l/not-enough-disk-space-for-apt-upgrade-on-beaglebone-ai (Uses the script)
- https://openthread.io/guides/border-router/beaglebone-black#expand-the-sd-card-image (Uses fdisk manually

I've tried this with a 16GB and 64GB SD Card. I have also tried using different images from https://beagleboard.org/latest-images, but they all seem to give the same result. I have a BeagleBone Black Rev. C.

Comment: *"sfdisk: BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy"* -- You cannot modify a partition that has its filesystem mounted.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I wasn't actually booting from my SD card, the [second tutorial](https://openthread.io/guides/border-router/beaglebone-black#expand-the-sd-card-image) I linked actually says you have to hold down a button to boot from your SD card. Once I did that, running `sudo /opt/scripts/tools/grow_partition.sh` worked just fine.

I'll have to research how to always boot from the SD card, but I'm assuming that's simple enough.